# What are some open source C++ projects with excellent coding style?

Tags: c++, coding-style, open-source

I'm looking for a **practical C++ coding style** for medium to large projects which **maximizes readability**.  I am indifferent to clever design patterns or constructs as long as the code is obvious when you browse it.

C++ style guides are also welcome, but I prefer to browse real code so I can easily determine if their guidelines do, in fact, effectively increase readability.

Comment: This is a subjective poll-type question. Not appropriate here. Please recheck the [faq].

Comment: not a technical question in the sense of syntax or semantics, but extremely relevant if you need to maintain or extend medium to large code bases - I am not looking for a vote - I am looking for good examples

Comment: From the FAQ: "(...) avoid asking subjective questions where …     every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” (...)".

Comment: Boost has excellent coding sytle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [ITK](http://www.itk.org/). It has a large codebase, but it's extremely coherent imho.

Comment: ty - I've currently use Kitware's cmake but I haven't heard of ITK - I will certainly take a look